# google-places-api / wordpress / display points of interest (restaurant, school, bakery..)

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I would like to display a google maps with information related to the city place (points of interests, such as school, restaurant, subway, ...), such as for NEXITY ( http://www.nexity.fr/neuf/98__98033 ).

Those points of interest would be displayed or not (by user's selection).
Those points of interest would be dynamic (up to date).

I use Wordpress.
Is there a plugin for that ?

Regards

Comment: let me know if you have questions regarding my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Radar Search Requests in Google Maps Javascript v3 API w/ Places services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests), which is a map with search results from Google.

Passing the `types` option, which is an array containing one or more of the supported types listed in the [Google Places API: Supported Place Types list](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types), the Google Maps Places Services would return a list of results base on your request.

I did some modification to [this demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search) to do what you want. Hope it helps :)

http://jsfiddle.net/j37vn47v/3/